# ASP.NET Core serves expired certificate

Tags: asp.net-core, ssl, certificate, kestrel

My SSL certificate for one of my websites expired on 23/1/2022. I renewed the certificate with the issuer, got all the new files (PEM,CRT), converted to PFX and replaced the original file at the server.

However, if I or anyone else visit the website, there is still warning of the invalid certificate and in the details in the browser I see the validity of the expired certificate.

I host my service in Ubuntu using Kestrel.

The configuration looks like this:

```
  webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel(serverOptions =>
                {
                    serverOptions.ConfigureHttpsDefaults(listenOptions =>
                    {
                        X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2("PKCS12_1556384.pfx", password);
                        listenOptions.ServerCertificate = certificate;
                    });
                });
```

I renamed the new certificate to keep the file name, so I do not need to recompile the source, replaced the original file (all the files related to the certificate, like the parent one I got from the issuer), rebooted the service couple of times, but nothing helped.

Answer (score 0):

In IIS, we can rebind the new certificate by `Enable Automatic Rebind if Renewed Certificate`.

So the best practise should be [how to rebind the renewed certificated](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-certbot-standalone-mode-to-retrieve-let-s-encrypt-ssl-certificates-on-ubuntu-16-04).